# Remove an item from a LIST using PartiQL and DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, partiql

Trying to remove an item from a list in DynamoDB using PartiQL and parameters.

This works with no problem

```
update table name REMOVE members[1] 
SET log=?
WHERE PK=? AND SK=?
```

but if I use a parameter for the list index - members[?] -  then I get the following error 'Execute PartiQL statement failed: Validation Error: Statement wasn't well formed, can't be processed: Invalid path component for simple path'

```
update table name REMOVE members[?] 
SET log=?
WHERE PK=? AND SK=?
```

Comment: Hey Stuart, did you find  solution for that problem? I have the same problem at the moment.